# Restrict mouseclick through <div> using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, openlayers

I have a screen where two things are displayed.

1. A Google street map is rendered using Openlayers.
2. A side panel is rendered to display a list of countries and their annual population growth.

Below code explains the idea.  Code is written in HTML.

```
<body>
 <div id="map" style="z-index:0;"></div>
 <div id="sidePanel" style="position:absolute;
                            top:0px;
                            left:0px;
                            width:30%;
                            height:100%;
                            z-index:1;
                            background-color:black">
 //content in this div will be filled dynamically through ajax call
 </div>
</body>
```

Everything displayed perfectly. But, when I click on `#sidepanel` and holding mouse click, if I drag, then `#map` is receiving the mouse click and 'Pan Operation' is occuring on screen.

I dont want '#map' to receive mouseclick when clicked on `#sidepanel`. Also, when I position mouse over `#sidepanel` and double click on that div, `#map` is receiving the double click and Zoom Operation is  happening . I want to separate `#map` and `#sidepanel`.

I am experiencing this problem only with Firefox and Chrome browsers. IE is working fine for my requirement.
Please suggest some ideas. Thanks for your patience.

HERE IS MY COMPLETE CODE

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.6"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="RenderGoogleMap();">
<div id="Map_Screen" style="z-index: -1;"></div>
<div id="sidePanel" style="overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:35%;height:100%;background-color:black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function RenderGoogleMap() {
        var options = {
            projection : "EPSG:900913",
            units : "m",
            maxResolution : 156543.0339,
            maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34,20037508.34, 20037508.34),
            displayProjection : new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        };
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('Map_Screen', options);
        var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("GoogleMap", { 'sphericalMercator' : true, numZoomLevels : 18 });
        map.addLayers([ gmap ]);
            map.zoomTo(3);
        var control = map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation() );
        control.activate();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because you've set the position of the sidePanel as absolute, and as a result the sidepanel div is on top of the map? Try removing the `position:absolute` from your sidePanel CSS code.

**Update:**

The problem was that the width of your map was set to 100%, and your sidepanel was overlayed on top of it. Instead of doing this, I kept your sidepanel at 35% width, added a 2% right margin, and set the map to be 62%. This way, you have the sidepanel and map not overlapping, so when you click on the sidepanel the map will not be affected in any way.

See the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>India</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.6"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function RenderGoogleMap() {
        var options = {
            projection : "EPSG:900913",
            units : "m",
            maxResolution : 156543.0339,
            maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34,20037508.34, 20037508.34),
            displayProjection : new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        };
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('Map_Screen', options);
        var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("GoogleMap", { 'sphericalMercator' : true, numZoomLevels : 18 });
        map.addLayers([ gmap ]);
        var control = map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation() );
        control.activate();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="RenderGoogleMap();">
<div id="sidePanel" style="float:left;width:35%;margin-right:2%;height:100%;background-color:black;"></div>
<div id="Map_Screen" style="float:left;width:62%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update 2:**

If you want the overlay but dont want the side panel to manipulate the map, try this code. It sets the map `z-index` to -1 and the overlay `z-index` to 999.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.6"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="RenderGoogleMap();">
<div id="Map_Screen" style="z-index: -1;"></div>
<div id="sidePanel" style="z-index:999;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:35%;height:100%;background-color:black;"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function RenderGoogleMap() {
        var options = {
            projection : "EPSG:900913",
            units : "m",
            maxResolution : 156543.0339,
            maxExtent : new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34,20037508.34, 20037508.34),
            displayProjection : new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        };
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('Map_Screen', options);
        var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("GoogleMap", { 'sphericalMercator' : true, numZoomLevels : 18 });
        map.addLayers([ gmap ]);
            map.zoomTo(3);
        var control = map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation() );
        control.activate();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried all of possible values for 'position' attribute, no use in changing the position attribute.

Comment: Can you share a link to the actual site where you're having this problem?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. If it works for you, please upvote and mark as correct :)

Comment: Yes, it worked. I have tried this approach before posting here. I thank for your help. But, I noticed that, you separated #Map_Screen div and #sidePanel div. I want the #sidePanel div to be overlayed on map at the same time, clicks on #sidePanel shouldnot reach #Map_Screen.

Comment: sorry, the functionality you provided is not close to my requirement. I think that, Overlaying #SidePanel over map would be good , so that, the #SidePanel div can be toggled(hide/show).

Comment: In the code in my second update the sidepanel is overlayed. If you want to toggle it, you can use some simple jQuery toggle. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Hey Charles, it worked exactly I wanted . Thank you very much for your support. I am done with my job now. Thanks Charles. :)

Comment: you know, till now my app was able to work only on IE . But now, with your solution , my app is able to run on firefox, chrome, IE. Thanks Charles.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript events are normally bubbled to other elements in a specific order in DOM, if the event handler doesn't intercept them in some way. Usually means that first the topmost (with highest z-index) element event handler is called, then the next one etc if nothing interferes with the bubbling.

You could attach an event handler that stops the bubbling to `#sidePanel` - this is done differently for different browsers. If you're using jQuery you could simply do

```
$("#sidePanel").on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

More about event bubbling
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

So you should catch all the events you for `#sidePanel` you need to block from bubbling to your `#map`. These might include `onmousedown`, `onmouseup` etc.

Comment: Yeah, I heard about this topic earlier. Thank you Marcus.